# Is this proof of the infinitude of primes valid?

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers

The current issue
(May 2015)
of the American Mathematical Monthly
has a one-line proof
that there are an infinite 
number of primes,
and I don't see why it is correct.

Here is the proof:

If the set of primes
is finite,
then

$$0
< \prod\limits_{p} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{p}\right)
= \prod\limits_{p} \sin\left(\frac{\pi(1+2\prod_{p'}p')}{p}\right)
=0
.$$

(That's the whole proof.)

I see why the first equality holds,
since, if there are only
a finite number of primes,
$p \mid \prod_{p'}p'$
for all $p$.

But I do not see why
the second equality
("$= 0$")
holds.
None of the terms
in the product
are zero,
and, since there are only
a finite number of them,
the product is not zero.

So,
do I not understand the proof,
or is the proof incorrect?

Thank you.

Comment: I *really* like the comments to Strants' answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We must have that $1+2\prod_{p'}p'$ is divisible by some prime $q$, so $1+2\prod_{p'}p' = kq$ for some integer $k$.  But then,
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi(1+2\prod_{p'}p')}{q}\right) = \sin \pi k = 0$$
which gives the right-hand equality.

Comment: Ah. I should have seen that. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good answer.  But...to me the proof reads like a joke, something like an answer to the question "What is the sine of Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes?"  Is there anything serious going on here?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark agreed; this is Euclid's proof made abstruse.  There may be no "royal road to geometry", but there is no reason to stick a needle in one's foot and hop towards understanding.

Comment: Isn't there a factor $2$ that is systematically missing here? Also, the fact that $1+\prod_{p'}p'$ is divisible by some prime $q$ is unrelated to the hypothesis that there are only a finite number of primes; it is based on the fact that this expression is${}>1$ and that every $n>1$ has a prime divisor (which must be proved separately).

Comment: @guest : This differs from "Euclid's proof made abstruse" in that Euclid's actual proof did not begin with an assumption that only finitely many primes exist: Euclid's proof was _not_ by contradiction.  Euclid showed that (rephrased into modern concepts) for every finite set $S$ of primes (which need not be the smallest $n$ primes for some $n$) the prime divisors of $1+\prod S$ are not in $S$.  Thus $S$ can always be extended to a larger finite set of primes. Dirichlet and many later mathematicians erroneously wrote that Euclid's proof was by contradiction. That's a naked emperor.

Comment: Catherine Woodgold and I had a joint paper in the Fall 2009 issue of the _Mathematical Intelligencer_ demonstrating that (1) the belief that Euclid's proof was by contradiction is false, and (2) that belief is widespread among mathematicians, and (3) the proof by contradiction is in some substantial respects inferior to Euclid's actual proof.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Then again, Euclid's proof was only about three primes ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : That's only if you construe his notation literally, which would be silly.  If you read his actual words rather than focusing on a detail of the notation, it is quite explicit that it is _not_ only about three primes.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks, I've added the factor of $2$.  I think you're right that $1+2\prod_{p'}p'$ is unrelated to the assumption that there are only finitely many primes: I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I *suppose* one could argue that this proof demonstrates how one can use inequalities to prove number-theoretic facts (I'm thinking of the proofs for the transcendence of $\pi$ and $e$).  But I'll also be the first to admit that this is a pretty weak reason.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: shouldn't your naked emperor be a straw man?

Comment: @TonyK : Why?  I straw man is a position that nobody takes.  The claim that Euclid's proof is by contradiction is a position that some people do take, including some otherwise very respectable mathematicians.  Ronald Graham, in an address to a plenary session at the Joint Meetings in San Antonio in January of this year took that position.  (It was a very good talk in all other respects.)  A naked emperor is a statement that is widely believed only because it is incessantly repeated and people have not stopped to think about it. Such is the claim that Euclid's proof is by contradiction.

Comment: I think Ronald Graham knows better now.

Comment: @MichaelHardy.  It was a light hearted comment.  Made in jest.  Just like Peter Clark's comment, it is not meant to imply some profound statement about Euclid's proof.  Our comments are quite clearly meant to imply: the key step in the proof above is Euclid's idea (analyzing divisors of a number of the form $P+1$ with $P$ a product of primes - to avoid any more need for tedious clarification), with a whole lot of unnecessary fluff at the top that obscures it.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It's a straw man because no one has even mentioned "proof by contradiction" except you, the issue is off topic for this discussion, and you failed to understand two jokes.

Comment: @A.Rex : You're mistaken.  Proof by contradiction is mentioned in the original question above, in the quote from the _Monthly_.  It says "If the set of primes is finite, then${}\,\ldots$".  That's proof by contradiction. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Above I wrote "The claim that Euclid's proof is by contradiction is a position that some people do take, including${}\,\ldots$", etc.  I forgot to mention that that position is indeed taken in the comments above. @guest wrote "this is Euclid's proof made abstruse", and the word "this" obviously meant the quote from the _Monthly_ which begins with "If the set of primes is finite", and is thus a proof by contradiction. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I already clarified that I was talking about Euclid's IDEA and not the METHOD of proof.  You are reading everything in a too literal sense, which I can understand, but to continue doing so after the point has been clarified, is getting rather tedious.  I know, and have known long before your comments, that Euclid did not formulate his proof by contradiction.

Comment: @guest : The reason I posted the comment above is that I was _responding_ to the comments by A.Rex. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: As a big fan of Hans Christian Andersen's classic tale (it's why I commented in the first place), I would like to point out that in that story everyone can see that the emperor wears no clothes, but nearly everyone is too afraid to point it out.  With regards to the infinitude of primes, it seems that most people are simply mistaken as to the content of Euclid's original proof (as many of us are about many other math history issues).  They are not afraid to reveal their true belief that it was a direct proof.  As such, I believe a "naked emperor" is a false analogy. Best,

Comment: @A.Rex : OK, it's not quite a naked emperor.  In this case people haven't looked to see whether the emperor is wearing anything.